# How to send an item in an array to the back and move the other items forward? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, int

How would you move a specific index to the back and move the others forward without converting to a list?

If for example you have the array xs: 20, 30, 40, 50, 60.
And you want xs to change to: 20, 40, 50, 60, 30

Any ideas?

Code I've used that doesn't work:

```
 if (indx >= 0 && indx < xs.Length)
 {
    for (int i = indx; i < xs.Length-1; i++)
    {
        int bb = xs[indx];                    
        xs[i +1] = xs[i];
        xs[xs.Length - 1] = bb;
    }     
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the code you've tried?

Comment: And is this homework with array-constraints or can we make sensible suggestions?

Comment: You can simply use `RemoveAt` and `Insert` methods.

Comment: It's not homework, so comment away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you swap you need to use the right positions:

```
for (int i = indx; i < xs.Length-1; i++)
{
    int tmp = xs[i];                    
    xs[i]   = xs[i+1];
    xs[i+1] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: The swapping doesn't need to be done for every array element. It would be sufficient to save the `xs[indx]` value before the loop, shuffle all of the subsequent values down in the loop, then store the saved value at the end of the array.

Comment: @HABO - yes, a small improvement. The OP origionally had those 2 versions mixed up. This is a simple version, not the fastest. It will be fast enough though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking.Create this method:

```
private static int[] SwapItem(int[] arr, int index)
{
    return arr.Where(i => i != arr[index]).Concat(new[] { arr[index] }).ToArray();
}
```

Then in your code use it like this:

```
int[] original = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var newArray = SwapItem(original, 1);
```

Output in this example using index 1 will be:

```
{ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2 }
```